# How to transfer postgres script to hsqldb script?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hsqldb, liquibase

I have a script, which I run successfully in postgres db, however it was failed when I run in hsqldb. 
Can someone help me change this sql to make it work for both HSQLDB and Postgres DB?
Below is my script:

```
UPDATE tableA af
SET columnA2 = b.columnB2
from
  ( select columnB1, columnB2 from.....) as b
Where af.columnA1 = b.columnB1;
```

This throws the following exception when I run it in hsqldb:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or
>   object not found: b.columnB2 Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user
>   lacks privilege or object not found: b.columnB2

Thanks.

---

Updated: 
I created another view to make my question more clear.

table_A has 2 columns: company_code, company_number
and view_B has 2 columns: company_code, company_number_correct_answer

table_A has 10000 rows, and view_B has only 2 rows. 
**What I want is updating 2 record in table_A**, with company_code existing in view_B and set table_A.company_number = view_B.company_number_correct_answer

Comment: Please post the entire query.  Note that HSQLDB and Postgres use substantially different syntax.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `from (select ... from b) as b` can be simplified to `from b` for Postgres

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I can't upload entire query because of private internal information. However the problem is that : HSQLDB doesn't understand alias.

Comment: You should use HQL or JPA then, which is database agnostic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: My system uses liquibase script to update data to table, and hsqldb is used in test environment. SpringBoot application built fail when run liquibase. That's why I said that I need to fix that plain query for both hsqldb and postgres.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, the FROM clause (or JOIN or similar things) is not valid for the UPDATE statement.

If you want an UPDATE statement that works across multiple database products, you will have to use a co-related sub-query:

```
update table_a
  set columna2 = (select columnb2
                  from table_b 
                  where table_b.columnb1 = table_a.columna1)
where exists (select * 
              from table_b 
              where table_b.columnb1 = table_a.columna1);
```

Note that this requires that `table_b.columnb1` is a unique or primary key, otherwise the sub-query would return more than one row which will lead to an error).

Comment: I can't use your query because it will update entire table_a with the same value for columna2. That's why I used alias and added WHERE clause outside. It worked in postgres, but in hsqldb it doesn't understand alias.

Comment: Updated my question. Can you please check.

Comment: @SonPham: you need a WHERE condition that only updates the rows where a match exists. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MERGE in HSQLDB

```
MERGE INTO tableA af
USING (select columnB1, columnB2 from.....) as b
ON af.columnA1 = b.columnB1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET af.columnA2 = b.columnB2
```